# PhpStorm last update - Can't see color change when value changes during debugging

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I updated my PhpStorm to the latest version:

[image]

Since this update, when I'm debugging my code, every value in "Debug -> Threads & Variables" is changing its color like it was evaluate, but before this update only the necessary value has been changing the color.

Does someone knows what is the problem and how to solve it?

An image for example:

[image]

The value that should have been change the color is `$pack_type`, but every value has been changed.

Already searched for solution on JetBrains website.